# Move dataframe column below the other(pandas Python)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I want to shift especific column down by one (I dont know if other library can help me)

```py
import pandas as pd
#pd.set_option('display.max_rows',100)
fac=pd.read_excel('TEST.xlsm',sheet_name="DC - Consumables",header=None, skiprows=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(fac)      


df1=df.iloc[0:864,20:39]

df2=df.iloc[0:864,40:59]

df1=pd.concat([df1,df2])

print (df1)
```

---

I want one column to be below the other column

```
A B C`     A B C`
1 2 3`     6 7 8`
4 5 8`     4 1 9`
```

---

my code print this

```
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 8
     A B C
     6 7 8
     4 1 9
```

---

### I need the second column (dataframe) to be below the first column, like this:

```
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 8
A B C
6 7 8
4 1 9
```

Please help me

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) instead post the data as a text so we can read using `pd.read_clipboard()` : Also please explain the question a bit. you may want to take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Try pd.concat().

```py
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Comment: I tried use pd.concat but its print the same. don't put it bellow